# How to pass data between activities and perform arithmetic operation on that data

Tags: android

I am new to Android
I have learned how to pass data between activites by putextra,getextra
in my app,when I pass data from **activity1** and **activity2** to **main_activity** and add the both data and pass it to third activity (**output**)
instead of addition ,only the value of either activity1 or activity2 is passing to output (value which is being passed is one which I entered last during running my app)
here is the code of my app
         **Mainactivity**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent j = getIntent();
        a= j.getDoubleExtra("double1",0.0);

        Intent k = getIntent();
       b = k.getDoubleExtra("double2",0.0);
         result = a+b;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void on_click_activity1button(View view) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,activity1.class);
                startActivity(intent1);

    }

    public void on_click_activity2button(View view) {
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(this,activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent2);

    }

    public void on_click_outputbutton(View view) {
        Intent intent3 = new Intent(this,output.class);
        intent3.putExtra("result", result);

        startActivity(intent3);

    }
}
```

**Activity1**

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity1);
    }
  public void on_click_activity1done(View view) {

        EditText text1 = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.activity1edittext);
        a=Double.parseDouble(text1.getText().toString());

        Intent fromactivity1 = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        fromactivity1.putExtra("double1", a);
        startActivity(fromactivity1);
    }
}
```

**Activity2.java**

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);
    }

    public void on_click_activity2done(View view) {

        EditText text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activity2edittext);
        b=Double.parseDouble(text2.getText().toString());

        Intent fromactivity2 = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        fromactivity2.putExtra("double2", b);
        startActivity(fromactivity2);
    }
}
```

**output.java**

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.output);
        Intent frommaindone = getIntent();
        Double total = frommaindone.getDoubleExtra("result",0.0);
        TextView show = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resulttextview);
       show.setText("addition is" + total);
    }
}
```

Please help me, and tell me what wrong I am doing

Comment: the way you are doing it is incorrect, you are creating multiple main activities and noone of the numbers will always be wrong. look into startActivityForResult

Comment: I also tried startActivityForResult but the same problem is occurring

Comment: when i run my app ,and press button1 to get textfrom(double) activity1 and after that when i press button 2 to get textfrom(double)  activity2,i think the value of variable from activity1 is destroyed. I want to know how to retain it so that i can add the two values a&b.

Comment: its because you are restarting the main activity. try the startActivityForresult and post your code here. make sure to setResult(myNumber) and finish in your activity and then override onActivityResult in your main activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use startActivityForResult method to get values from two input activities and then pass the result to output activity.Change your code as below and try.

**Activity1**

public class Activity1 extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity1);
}

public void on_click_activity1done(View view) {

    EditText text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activity1edittext);
    double b = Double.parseDouble(text1.getText().toString());

    Intent result = new Intent();
    result.putExtra("double1", b);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
    finish();

}
```

}

**Activity2.java**

```
public class Activity2 extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity2);
    }


    public void on_click_activity2done(View view) {

        EditText text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activity2edittext);
        double b = Double.parseDouble(text2.getText().toString());

        Intent result = new Intent();
        result.putExtra("double2", b);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
        finish();

    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private final int  ACTIVITY1 = 1;
    private final int  ACTIVITY2 = 2;
    private double result, double1,double2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void onActivityOneClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY1);
    }

    public void onActivityTwoClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY2);  
    }

    public void on_click_outputbutton(View view) {
        result = double1 + double2;
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, OutPut.class);
        intent.putExtra("result", result);
        startActivity(intent);  
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            switch(requestCode){
            case ACTIVITY1:     
                double1 = data.getDoubleExtra("double1", 0);
                break;
            case ACTIVITY2:
                double2 = data.getDoubleExtra("double2", 0);
                break;
            }                   
        }
    }
}
```

**OutPut.java**

```
public class OutPut extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.output);

        double total = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("result", 0);     
        TextView show = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resulttextview);
        show.setText("addition is" + total);
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you very very much..  I was fighting with the problem from last two days I tried making variable static, using startActivityforResult,using Bundle etc but nothing worked , you used switch case to solve the problem ,can u please explain me what i was doing wrong and how did you get to the solution

Comment: When app runs it creates an instance MainActivity but you create two new instances of MainActivity by calling startactivity from your two input activities. So when you click output button on last created instance of mainactivity it will show only the the value you enter on last input activity.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible that your code work, because when you come back and save one value and go out for another, you lost the old value.

In my opinion, you are doing a bad approach for this problem, but if you really want to do this, the only thing I have for you is use a static variable although I don't recommend this. So, create two static variables on MainActivity, when save data, to do it there, and when you want to go to output, send the operation between the two. This way work.